# Why is there no (definite) article before "unity" in the mathematical sense?

Tags: definite-article, mathematics

Example:

> x is equal to unity

("unity" has to do with a "unit", i.e. 1, not "the state of being joined together or in agreement".)

Comment: Actually, no not _obviously_ since there is such little context in your post. Second, that's actually not true. I'm assuming that you are talking about (abstract/modern) algebra. Then _unity_ is not the same as a _unit_.

Comment: I took the equality "unity = unit" from the dictionary. Does not “x is equal to unity” mean simply x=1? Anyway, is not unity here a countable noun?

Comment: Very loosely speaking, yes. Here is one definition with which I am familiar: _A ring with a multiplicative identity element is a **ring with unity**; the multiplicative identity element 1 is called "**unity**."_ There might be (probably are) other definitions of _unit_ and _unity_ with which I am unfamiliar.  _Unity_ is a _unit_, but not all _units_ are _unity_ (ie 1).

Comment: I would be content with a simpler definition: one, sometimes referred to as *unity*, is the first non-zero natural number. It is thus the integer before two and after zero, and the first positive odd number.(Wikipedia). But neither definition explains the absense of the article in my example (in **your** example it is less surprising)

Comment: [This mathematical glossary](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/int_domain2.shtml#unity) uses the indefinite article with _unity_, in each of the 13 times _unity_ is used on that page.

Comment: Well, being content with a simpler definition doesn't mean you'll be answering the question. The framing and the assumptions need to all match. Anyway, for more context, 1 is just a label, not necessarily the number one. For example, 0 (zero) is the multiplicative inverse in the zero ring. So in the zero ring, zero the unity and so you can say zero is 1, or that 1=0 (mind blown, haha). That is why sometimes, we specify that the 1 not equal 0.

Comment: It seems to me we could refer to "a unity" when discussing the mathematical conception, and "the unity" when referring to an instance, or just "unity" when presented as a statement in maths, as it is here!

Comment: Because *unity* is generally uncountable in mathematics, while *unit* is countable. The mathematical glossary that uses *a unity*, mentioned in the comments above, was probably either written by non-native speakers or by non-mathematicians. (It actually seems to be written by a Russian mathematician currently living in the U.S.)

Comment: By the way, I did not mean to suggest that I was an expert on the matter, as I too am unsure about the usage of the article.  I am also curious about the answer. This is so interesting. _Uncountable_ has a special meaning in math and I think it actually (incidentally, accidentally)  forces _unity_ to be an _uncountable noun_. Very interesting.

Comment: I really hope @BenKovitz drops in on this thread.....

Comment: When I was in graduate school, there was a little heat within the department about whether rings _had to_ have a unity.  One particularly bombastic professor bellowed out that _"Every ring **must** have unity!  Some people will try to define rings without unity, and they spell them like this_ [`blackboard:` **rng**] _"They say this is pronounced 'rung.'  I say it is pronounced 'wrong.'"_

Answer (score -1):

You are using

> unit
>   unity

...in their sense as mathematical jargon to mean 1.0. They are synonymous.

"Unit" or "unity" are used in this way when values are scaled so that their sum equals 1.0.

> unit length
>   unit vector

Doing so makes "general" calculations easier.

One would not say

> equal to *the* unit
>   *equal to the 1.0*

since "unit" is representational shorthand for a number.

Comment: -1: If one were a mathematician, one would most definitely say *equal to **the** unit*. Mathematicians treat *unity* as a mass noun and *unit* as a countable noun, probably because this is the way they're treated in ordinary English.

Comment: I think that mathematicians treat _unity_ as a name.